# Getting error in Jpa query with spring-boot

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot

From the server log I am getting the below error

```
    o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : 
    Written [{timestamp=Fri May 15 01:39:47 EDT 2015, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException, message=Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
    unexpected error when rollbacking, 
    path=/api/act}] 
    as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@6dc2f5d0]
```

**Edit:**

```
     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3661)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2417)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4846)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:159)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:439)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3643)
        ... 71 common frames omitted

2015-05-16 05:02:11.546 ERROR   --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking] with root cause

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3643)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2417)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4846)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:159)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:439)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.findByUserid(Unknown Source)
        at com.aerod.socialapis.controller.UserActivityContoller.createOrDeleteFeed(UserActivityContoller.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.aerod.socialapis.service.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:22)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And When I am calling the api I am getting response like

```
{
"timestamp": 1431668344518,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException",
"message": "Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: ",
"path": "/api/act"
}
```

Here is my application.property

```
# DataSource settings: set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/api
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Specify the DBMS
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate settings are prefixed with spring.jpa.hibernate.*
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Here is my application class

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public Application webSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new Application();
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter characterEncodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return characterEncodingFilter;
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

Here is my controller code

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public String createUser( @RequestBody  User user){
                        userDao.save(user);
                        return ("Done");

            }
        }
```

Here is my Dao

```
@Transactional
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the actual problem and how to solve this?If more information needed feel free to ask.

Comment: Is the transaction system enabled ( @EnableTransactionManagement)

Comment: No I haven't done it.Can you clarify more how to use it?

Comment: How are you configuring the beans? Annotations or xml?

Comment: You can follow this Spring configuration one in my github:  https://github.com/nitindandriyal/atm-transaction-service/blob/master/atm-transaction-service/src/main/java/com/hackertrail/challenge/service/JPAConfiguration.java

Comment: @NitinDandriyal Should I have to add Jpa configuration extra because it was running good.After some time say after 6 hours it is throwing this type of exception.I want to know what is the actual problem

Comment: Is it possible that this error happened only when the transaction was called for the first time after running for say 6 hours? As @mh-dev also pointed out `@EnableTransactionManagement` is required for JPA transactions in Spring boot.

Comment: Where I have to mention @EnableTransactionManagement this?Can you please give me any hint?

Comment: On any spring configuration class. For example the class with the main.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your reply.I will check that if it helps..Can you answer this question,so later I can accept it

Comment: If it resolves your problem of course

Comment: Check your application log for a full stack trace, there is currently too little information to resolve your issue. Looks like a transaction cannot be started, generally this means misconfiguration of the datasource (wrong URL or username/password combo).

Comment: @M. Deinum he says that Application runs fine for few hours and then this happens. I think if it was DB config it would have failed sooner, I suspect its a transaction config issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum .Ok I understand but the weird thing is this error occurs after some certain time.Not when the application starts,so it can't be username/password combo otherwise it will throw exception at the startup. May be I have to add some more datasource or deduct some.

Comment: Does it happen when you access the db for the first time?

Comment: nope.All the problem occurs after certain time.

Comment: Can you post the whole exception?

Comment: Then post some code that is doing data access. Looks like your pool is starving (i.e. connections aren't freed) which generally comes from the fact that things are being done wrong (i.e. working around instead of with the framework).

Comment: @M.Deinum posted some code.Ask if you need some more?

Comment: @mh-dev posted the stacktrace

Comment: Than search the net for hibernate mysql broken pipe. Thats actually the error you have. Its related to the datasource which is constantly held open by hibernate but times out after a couple of hours.

Comment: @Soham - how did you resolve this issue, please share because I am having the same issue here.

@mh-dev - do I need to have `@EnableTransactionManagement` this annotation in my Application.java ? or anything I need to do ?

Comment: @webgeek .I couldn't solve it.If I would be able to solve it,I will surely share my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add this config to your application.properties add retest :

```
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I was able to solve it,but forgot to answer my question.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am still getting the same exception.By the way I am using this repo. [spring-boot-multitenant](https://github.com/rcandidosilva/spring-boot-multitenant)